# Bootstrap Conditional Queries based on columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3.x to create a responsive website. When the screen size if col-xs-12 I want to set a margin-left of -20px and when it is of sizes col-md-3, col-sm-4 and col-lg-2 I want a margin-left of 0px. However, it seems that the col-xs-12 margin-left: -20px is always being applied regardless of the screen size. How can I adjust this to get the desired result. My html and css is the same order as below:

CSS:

```
.control.col-xs-12{
    margin-left:-20px;  
}

.control.col-sm-4,.control.col-md-3,.scontrol.col-lg-2{
    margin-left:0px;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="control col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg-pull-10 col-md-pull-9 col-sm-pull-8 col-xs-pull-0 featcol">
    <img src="http://www.example.com/example.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: The -20px margin will always apply because you have the style rule written and it is always being added to your HTML. When working with different "responsive" CSS you need to look at using media-queries as this takes device browser size into consideration... If you use a media-query you can change override an existing style declaration or define new ones. I also don't think you're understanding that the Bootstrap columns are fluid width (percentage) so you can't ask for "when the page is equal to col-md-3 I want col-xs-12 to...". You need to use a browser width when you want the margin to be 0

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for clarifying that, it seems to work with the media queries. If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I haven't provided a solution for your submitted code, an understanding of the problem will allow you to understand (and thus generate) a solution...

Because you have your `col-xs-12` class in your HTML the styles it has defined will always be applied - regardless of browser size.

What you need to do is find a way of overriding its styles when your browser size changes - this is where **media queries** come in.

Media queries allow dynamic changes to CSS when the browser size changes.

An added problem you have with Bootstrap (well, not a problem at all because of its nature) is that the columns it has are all fluid width - i.e. they use percentage widths - so you cannot say you want the media query to activate when the Bootstrap elements are in the configuration you want. Media queries only work on the **browser size** so your media query can only activate when the browser reaches your desired size - to produce the layout you desire.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers this problem can be solved with media queries.
Since XS is defined as < 768px change the CSS like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .control{
    margin-left:-20px;  
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .control{
    margin-left:0px;  
  }
}
```

In general the second part where margin-left is defined as 0 will be unnecessary unless you want to override other styles.